# can you declare a class member as either a property or method?

Tags: typescript

given the following classes

```
class Base {
  options?: (() => any) | object | undefined;
}

class A extends Base {
  options() {}
}
```

where options could either be an object or a function that returns an object, how do I properly type this up? right now I'm getting an error that says "class A defines instance member property options but extended class Base defines it as an instance member function"

Comment: Is turning `Base` into an `interface` an option? If you make that change, it compiles fine on my end.

Comment: I don't think I can, I'm trying to create a declaration file for this class in an old third party library

Comment: Can you do `options = () => {}` in `A` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzOQ4w)? Eventually TypeScript will default to `--useDefineForClassFields` and then the `options` declaration in `Base` will set `options` to `undefined`, which will then take precedence over any prototype method in a subclass.  So what you are doing is probably a bad idea; either make `options` a method or a property consistently.

Comment: @jcalz yes, `options = () => {}` will work, thanks!  It's third party code so I don't really have the option to change the implementation :-/

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot declare a class member as either a property or method in TypeScript.